# REST API in sonarQub Version 8.9.1 community edition

Tags: python, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 8.9.1 comunity edition

I'm trying to retrieve Sonar list of groups members using Python. But unfortunatly i'm not getting exact syntax for getting results.

Here's my code:

```
import requests

sonarqube_url = 'https://sonar-stg/sonar'  
api_url = sonarqube_url + '/api'


username = '****'  
password = '****'  

def get_api_data(endpoint, params=None):
    response = requests.get(api_url + endpoint, auth=(username, password), params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print('Error in GET request:', response.status_code)
        return None

def extract_group_members(group_name):
    params = {'groupName': group_name}
    response = get_api_data('/user_groups/users', params=params)
    if response:
        members = response['users']
        return members
    else:
        return []

# Call the function to extract members of a SonarQube group
group_name = 'sonar-group'  
group_members = extract_group_members(group_name)

# Display the members of the group
print(f'Members of SonarQube Group "{group_name}":')
for member in group_members:
    print(member['login'])
```

output result:
`Error in GET request: 400`
`Members of SonarQube Group "sonar-group":(no result)`